# How to parse this JSON response into a key & value pairs array

Tags: objective-c, json, parsing, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

there are a lot of questions like this and i'm experienced with json format too but i couldnt parse the response below(at the bottom):

I'm using NSJSONSerialization for parsing the response into NSDictionary but the it gives the error like below:

**My code:**

```
     NSString *subURL= sharedDa.ip;
        NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.69.230/tsadmin.php?tssearch=%@", subURL]]];

        NSError *error=nil;
        NSDictionary* portsResult=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:
                              NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
  NSDictionary * tempPorts;
    NSString *k;

        for(k in [portsResult allKeys]){
            tempPorts = [portsResult objectForKey:k];
            NSLog(@"Temporary ports: %@", tempPorts);
        }
```

**And the error code is below:**

```
2012-09-28 18:47:37.508 BNTPRO ST Manager[2609:fb03] -[__NSArrayM allKeys]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6b83ed0
2012-09-28 18:47:37.511 BNTPRO ST Manager[2609:fb03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM allKeys]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6b83ed0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1568022 0x1b20cd6 0x1569cbd 0x14ceed0 0x14cecb2 0x57cd 0x28fa1e 0x28fd11 0x2a18fd 0x2a1aef 0x2a1dbb 0x2a285f 0x2a2e06 0x2a2a24 0x3e59 0x2595c5 0x2597fa 0xaee85d 0x153c936 0x153c3d7 0x149f790 0x149ed84 0x149ec9b 0x245a7d8 0x245a88a 0x1c8626 0x26d2 0x2645 0x1)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

now my data snippet is: `[{"k1":{"v":"0"}},{"k2":{"v":"0"}},{"k3":{"v":"0"}},{"k4":{"v":"0"}},{"k5":{"v":"0"}},{"k6":{"v":"0"}},{"k7":{"v":"1"}},{"k8":{"v":"0"}},{"k9":{"v":"1"}},{"k10":{"v":"0"}},{"k11":{"v":"1"}},{"k12":{"v":"0"}},{"k13":{"v":"1"}},{"k14":{"v":"0"}},{"k15":{"v":"0"}},{"k16":{"v":"0"}}]`
but it still gives the same error.. even i decşare the iVar as NSDictionary why does it complain of nsmutable array??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JSON you're parsing is an *array*, not an *object*. So the result of `[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData...]` is not an `NSDictionary *`, but an `NSArray *` instead.

For example, for the JSON data

```
[{"k1":{"v":"0"}}, {"k2":{"v":"0"}}]
```

You can use something similar to this code (don't have xcode right now to try to run it):

```
NSArray * arr = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:...];
int i;
for (i = 0; i < [arr count]; i++) {
    NSDictionary * dic = [arr objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString * k;
    for (k in [dic allKeys]) {
        NSLog(@"Temporary ports: %@", [dic objectForKey:k]);
    }
}
```

Comment: how to convert that array to a dictionary?

Comment: You can't - an array is an array, a dictionary is a dictionary. You can traverse the array as an array. I've updated the answer with an example of that.