# Filtering data with changeable key by it's value

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, filtering, nspredicate

I'm currently working on a project where I get JSON responce which looks this way:

> {"1":"qwerttt","2":"asdasda"}

I'm using Objective-c. I know how to filter data with the predicate knowing the key name. It could look like this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"city contains[c] %@", searchText];
```

But I don't understand what should I write in this case when the key name is not the same for each pair. Should I write my own filter, create a special dictionary or array in a comfortable format or do something else?Any help would be appreciated.

Updated: This is what I get when I parse json

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with that data afterwards? I'd suggest you parse it into a NSDictionary. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643334/how-to-parse-this-json-response-into-a-key-value-pairs-array

Comment: I do parse it in NSDictionary and get what I'll add to the post

Comment: ok and what exactly do you want to search for now?

Comment: I want to write a proper predicate if it is possible for filtering the data I get and I'm not sure how to do that.  I mean what should I write instead of the word city here: predicateWithFormat:@"city contains[c] %@" ?

Comment: Try to filter the NSDictionary with this *[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", yourSearchingString]*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
[[_regions allValues] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
                     [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS[c] %@",
                                  "RegionImSearchingFor"]];
```